# Conversion error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL query that gets a date (one parameter of start date and end date separated by a comma) as a parameter and should returns all values between these dates.

(Long query - I'm posting just the relevant part)

```
Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'And (o.Date >= LEFT(''' + @Date + ''', charindex('','',''' + @Date+ ''') - 1)' 
+ ' AND o.Date <= RIGHT(''' + @Date + ''', charindex('','',''' + @Date+ ''') - 1)) '
```

The format of the date parameter is:

```
start date,end date in MM,DD,YYYY format
```

When the date parameter is for example: `8-5-2015,08-9-2016` it's working perfectly, but when it is for example `8-5-2015,08-11-2016` I'm getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

I think it's related to the two digits on the days part.

Any idea what can causes that?

Comment: Split `@Date` outside of the expression, save the parts into variables of type `datetime` using [`convert` with explicit format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_4), and call your built query with [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) passing the dates as parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be problem with logic inside Right function. Please use below logic , i have added length function to find right date correctly.

```
Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'And (o.Date >= LEFT(''' + @Date + ''', charindex('','',''' + @Date+ ''') - 1)' 
+ ' AND o.Date <= RIGHT(''' + @Date + ''', len(''' + @Date+ ''') - charindex('','',''' + @Date+ '''))) '
```

Answer (score 1):

change the query to following type:

Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'And (o.Date >= LEFT(''' + @Date + ''', charindex('','',''' + @Date+ ''') - 1)' 
+ ' AND o.Date <= RIGHT(''' + @Date + ''', LEN(''' + @Date+ ''') - charindex('','',''' + @Date+ '''))) '

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is the correct answer and I up-vote you for that, I chose @BhatiaAshish as the correct answer even though you answered the same answer **before** because your answer is not properly formatted. Please see how to [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)